# Symfony multiple forms and inputs

Tags: symfony

I want make a page in which there are multiple posts(in the same page) and every post has a form and input inside that form in that input you can write something about that post, then text and post id are sent to database. How can i do that with symfony?

Comment: This type of questions are normally deleted or closed as too broad or off-topic (if you are looking for a free coding service or for a tutorial). You can only read the docs to learn how symfony works, then you will have the basic knowledge to write some code and return here to get an help for a specific problem related to your code. Read also: [what topics can you ask on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), these topics will help you to formulate a better question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually very simple. Make your Entities and formtype as you are used too. The trick is to paste the Post Id into the action URL of the forms so that it renders

```
<form action="/reaction/new/1">
```

where the 1 is the Post id. I used the Twig controller function to render each form with the correct action URL:

```
{{ render(controller('AppBundle:Reaction:new', {'postId':post.id})) }}
```

**Example**

Post entity:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * Post
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="post")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\PostRepository")
 */
class Post
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Reaction", mappedBy="post")
     */
    private $reactions;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->reactions = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    // ...
}
```

Reaction Enity:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Reaction
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="reaction")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ReactionRepository")
 */
class Reaction
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Post", inversedBy="reactions")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="post_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $post;

    // ...
}
```

Post controller:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

/**
 * Post controller.
 *
 * @Route("post")
 */
class PostController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="post_index")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $posts = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Post')->findAll();

        return $this->render('post/index.html.twig', array(
            'posts' => $posts,
        ));
    }
}
```

Reaction controller:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\Reaction;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 * Reaction controller.
 *
 * @Route("reaction")
 */
class ReactionController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Creates a new reaction entity.
     *
     * @Route("/new/{postId}", name="reaction_new")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function newAction(Request $request, $postId)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $reaction = new Reaction();
        $form = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\ReactionType', $reaction, array(
            /*
             * You must change the action otherwise we will post to Post:index action !
             */
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('reaction_new', array('postId' => $postId))
        ));
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
        {
            /*
             * load post entity and add it to the reaction::post collection !
             */
            $post = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Post')->find($postId);
            $reaction->setPost($post);

            $em->persist($reaction);
            $em->flush($reaction);

            /*
             * return to the post page
             */
            return $this->redirectToRoute('post_index');
        }

        return $this->render('reaction/new.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
}
```

post/index.html.twig:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    {% for post in posts %}
        <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
        <p>{{ post.body }}</p>
        <h3>Reactions</h3>
        <ul>
        {% for reaction in post.reactions %}
            <li>{{ reaction.message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {{ render(controller('AppBundle:Reaction:new', {'postId':post.id})) }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

reaction/new.html.twig:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
{{ form_end(form) }}
```